# iOS GCD Sync with Async Block

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, block, grand-central-dispatch

I have an async function with a block :

```
[self performAsyncTaskCompletion:(void(^) () )
 {
   //Do Something
 }
];
```

I need to call this function many times but in a synchronous way. I tried to use GCD queues :

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.MyApp.task", NULL);
for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++)
{
   dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
     [self performAsyncTaskCompletion:(void(^) () )
      {
        //Do Something
      }
      ];
   });
}
```

But it doesn't work because dispatch_sync is only waiting for the end of the block. 
How can I ask it to wait for the end of the async functions in its block ?

Comment: Can these `performAsyncTaskCompletion` blocks run concurrently with respect to each other? Or do you need one to wait for the previous one to finish. Also, I know you're asking to wait at the end of the block, but that's invariably the wrong pattern. Usually we let it run asynchronously, but just specify a block of code that will be run when all those other dispatched blocks are done. Does that work for you?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to do. Actually, I want to download (asynchronously) a bunch of different JSON files from a webserver. Imagine that each JSON leads me to another JSON to download. It is possible that I have already downloaded the next JSON, so I just have to perform a synchronous task to get it from an Array. So, the JSON downloads should be sync. At the end I need a block saying "Alright, everything is downloaded". What kind of pattern should I use ?

Comment: You say "imagine each JSON leads me to another". Are you saying that each is truly dependent upon the prior one? Generally one wants to maximize concurrency, but if every JSON requires data from the one that precedes it, that limits you.

Comment: Yes, I need the prior one to get more infos. I have to download 2 JSON : B & C; but both of them leads me to another JSON A to get more infos.

Comment: If A depends on B and C, but B and C can run concurrently, then you should do that. Use concurrency where possible and establish dependencies (or trigger them in the completion blocks) where needed.

Comment: So I should download B & C concurrently, get what they are linked to; and at the end, download A ?

Comment: Yep, whatever logical dependencies are, honor those, but to the extent possible, run concurrently whatever you can. If you really only have three requests, it might only have modest impact, but the more requests you issue, the more significant the impact.

Comment: this question and its answers are in objective-c, not swift. by using the swift tag you cause this answer to come up inappropriately during searches. I need an answer to a related question but it *must* be in Swift, and this question keeps coming up when it shouldn't. please remove the swift tag and I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: My bad ! I removed the tag :)

Comment: Thank you much! I removed the downvote. Best of luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use dispatch group if you want to initiate some process upon the completion of a series of asynchronous tasks, but would like to allow those tasks to run concurrently with respect to each other (which, especially with network requests, can offer much better performance than running them sequentially):

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {
    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    [self performAsyncTaskCompletion: ^{
        //Do Something
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    }];
}

dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // do this when its all done
});
```

Personally, I'd might even be inclined to perform a more radical refactoring of `performAsyncTaskCompletion`, using an asynchronous `NSOperation` subclass pattern instead. Then you could add these to a `NSOperationQueue` with `maxConcurrentOperationCount` specified, thereby achieving the same concurrency while also controlling the degree of concurrency. But hopefully the above illustrates the idea: Run tasks concurrently, but detect the completion of those tasks without ever blocking the main thread.

Comment: Thanks :) 
`performAsyncTaskCompletion` relies on AFNetworking, I can't really modify it.

Comment: First, if you're using `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`  or `AFHTTPRequestOperation`, then you're already using operation queue based solution (and I'd then set up standard `NSOperation` dependencies for your completion operation). And even if you're using `AFHTTPSessionManager`, you can still wrap these within your own `NSOperation` subclass. Neither of these require modifying AFNetworking, but rather just `performAsyncTaskCompletion`. Regardless, the notify approach still works, too. But, do not do this stuff synchronously.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dispatch_async` with [semaphores](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW37):

Example:

```
- (void)performAsyncTaskCompletion:(void (^)())block {
    if (block) {
        block();
    }
}

- (void)runChainOfOperations {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore;
    static dispatch_queue_t queue;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);
        queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.MyApp", NULL);
    });

    NSArray *array = @[@1, @2, @3, @4, @5];

    static long counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore,  DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

            [self performAsyncTaskCompletion:^{
                sleep(10);

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                     NSLog(@"%ld", counter++);
                });

                dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
             }];  
        });
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
2015-04-12 21:28:06.047 HKTest[9497:1136830] 0
2015-04-12 21:28:16.023 HKTest[9497:1136830] 1
2015-04-12 21:28:26.025 HKTest[9497:1136830] 2
2015-04-12 21:28:36.029 HKTest[9497:1136830] 3
2015-04-12 21:28:46.031 HKTest[9497:1136830] 4
```

Comment: Very nice answer ! Can you tell me how to call a block back from runChainOfOperations when the async tasks are finished ?

Comment: You' d add one more dispatch_async block right after for loop.

Comment: I think your example gives a wrong way to use 'semaphore', there is no useful of 'dispatch_semaphore_wait' in your example